# E R Chart Joint js: dynamic placement of nodes on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, jointjs

I am trying to create E R Chart using open source library - Joint js. 
The only issue I have is placement of nodes on chart, joint js expects to provide node position x & y co ordinates, however I am creating E R chart for which the nodes will be dynamically added or removed as for every user entity type I am creating a separate table. Is there any algorithm available which I can run and calculate x & y before placing them on canvas?

I am fine with any other library suggestion.The only constraint is, it should be open source.